# Nginx SSL config is slow

Tags: nginx, ssl, performance

I'm having some issues with my SSL configuration being slow. Generally, my site responds in under 125ms when I'm connecting via HTTP, but over 400ms when connecting over HTTPS. I've tried tweaking the config, but I honestly don't know what the best approach is for getting fast connections. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated

**Site Config**

```
upstream backend  {
    least_conn;

    server 10.132.42.217:3000;
    server 10.132.39.94:3000;
    server 10.132.66.78:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example/2017/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example/2017/server.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 30m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!DH;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:30m;

    client_max_body_size 500M;

    location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
        root /var/www/example/example/public/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        add_header X-Nginx-Server 'nginx1';
        add_header X-Upstream $upstream_addr;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: How slow is your server?

Comment: It's a $10/month digital ocean droplet, but resource usage is super low.

Comment: Try testing its response with [SSLTest](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). This should give you an idea of any issues with the SSL response.

Comment: I get an 'A' rating on SSLTest. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=kernl.us  The only thing that I did notice was that when I used https://www.wormly.com/test_ssl it threw a flag because my cert chain is 6KB versus the recommended 4KB or under.